# Godot 4 - How to render a pre-rendered isometric background with 3d models?

Tags: godot

I am trying to make a game with a pre-rendered isometric background rendered onto a quad. I  have a camera rendered in a bird's eye view down onto the quad with the background image as a material. This looks fine, however, the camera also renders 3d characters in a top-down way, when I want the characters to be rendered in an isometric way.

In summary, my camera is at a -90 degree angle looking directly down at the quad with the pre-rendered background,  and my 3d characters do not look correct as I am looking directly down at them. How do you solve this?

Comment: Does this help? [Isometric camera location](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Isometric_camera_location_35.264_degrees_color.png)